# show the dialog box with error message when user selects the same value as selected in other column of the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a html table with multiple rows and columns. In each row of the table i have two columns(Product1 and Product2) which holds the dropdown list where
user can select the value from list and submit the information. I want to keep a validation so that if user selects the same products
from two columns in the same row a dialog box should pop up showing the message "Product1 and Product2 cannot be same for same ID". Similarly for other rows also, when user selects the same value from the columns Product1 and Product2 it should show the error message..

Example: When user select the product Laptop from Product1 column and again selects the product Laptop from Product2 column or vice versa of PID 100 then a dialog box should be shown with the message "Product1 and Product2 cannot be same for same ID".

Demo link : http://plnkr.co/edit/HZZlQIiItG6b5IAeEkUq?p=preview

When user selects some value from dropdown list it is calling the onchange event function shown below, but my code is not working as expected.
It is not showing the dialog box with message when user selects the same products in Product1 and Product2 columns of each row..
Any inputs would be helpful.
below is the sample code i tried:

```
   //onchange of the dropdown list 
     $("select").change(function() 
     {  
        var product1_drop = $('.product1').val(); // Get selected value of product1 dropdown
        var product2_drop = $('.product2').val(); // Get selected value of product2 dropdown
        console.log("product1_drop " + product1_drop);
        console.log("product2_drop " + product2_drop);
           if(product1_drop == product2_drop ){       
                  alert('Product name in two drop down list cannot be same..');
                 }
      });
```

html code:

```
<table id="productTable" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>PID</th>
        <th>Select Product1</th>
        <th>Select Product2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>100</td>
         <td>
                           <select class="product1" > 
                           <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                 <td>
                           <select class="product2" >        
                            <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
      </tr>
     ......
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with these lines of code.

```
var product1_drop = $('.product1').val();
var product2_drop = $('.product2').val();
```

The query '.product1' will select all elements with the class product1. Then .val() returns the value from the first one.

My suggestion is to get the containing table row. Then select the elements with the class product1 and product2 that are in that row.

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
```